# Implementing MVVM, Dagger2, Retrofit, Rxjava, LiveData, ViewModel together along with Android testing

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, dagger

I have knowledge of `MVVM, Dagger2, Retrofit, Rxjava, LiveData, ViewModel`. I did a basic implementation of them together without `Fragments` https://github.com/karthik5418/android--demo/tree/snapdeal_search

Now I have some doubts in going advanced implementation of them

1. Do I need to learn `DataBinding` (i.e is it necessary to get clean code and for testing)
2. I gone through few blogs for advanced implementation, every blogs is has its own way. Some looks higher level of abstraction, that I thing is not necessary

reference : https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture

https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-using-livedata-rxjava-and-new-dagger-android-injection-639837b1eb6c

https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe

I am confused now, what should I follow for my production ?

Please help me with some reference that I can follow for my production.

Comment: well if you learn data binding, thousand of code will be reduced, easy to understand of coding, redundant of boiler plate code and so many things you get.

Comment: @Hemant : it helps in testing also ?

Comment: yes, i am using it frequently.

Comment: Please visit: https://medium.com/@saquib3705/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-with-the-help-of-mvvm-dagger-livedata-and-rxjava2-in-67aebefe031d

Answer (score 0):

check out this repo https://github.com/balwinderSingh1989/MVVMCleanAndroid that contains a architecture structure that you use to kick start your project.

And yes, you should be learning databinding (there's hardly any learning curve involved). Also make sure you explore about binding adapters as well.